# Best way to create a subclass object based on a command line argument

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, factory, abstract-factory

I have several subclasses that extend a superclass, and I want to let the command line interface user select which subclass to use. All subclasses have the same constructor form.

For example, I want to be able to call `run --subclass=Subclass1`, resulting in a call to `Subclass obj = new Subclass(arg1, arg2)`. I can think of several ways to do this, but I figure this pattern comes up often enough that there's a standard or accepted way to do it; if not, I want to do what's most elegant and simple.

Here is my current proposal (assuming there is a `Namespace` object that contains the command line arguments):

```
SuperClass createObject(Namespace namespace, 
                        ArgumentClass1 arg1, 
                        ArgumentClass2 arg2) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Class<? extends SuperClass>> classMap =
        ImmutableMap.<String, Class<? extends SuperClass>>builder()
            .put("subclass1", SubClass1.class)
            .put("subclass2", SubClass2.class)
            .build();
    Constructor<? extends SuperClass> constructor =
        classMap.get(namespace.getString("subclass"))
            .getConstructor(ArgumentClass1.class, ArgumentClass2.class);
    return constructor.newInstance(arg1, arg2);
}
```

When the subclass constructors all take no arguments, this can be simplified by not using a `Constructor` and doing `return classMap.get(namespace.get("subclass")).newInstance();`. Note that one drawback is that this can throw one of several exceptions (`InstantiationException`, `IllegalAccessException`, `NoSuchMethodException`, `InvocationTargetException`) that need to be handled either here or upstream.

Is this reasonable? Is it the best way to go? Is there a standard pattern to use?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to create a factory class for each subclass and put instances of those factories into your `classMap`. This will help you to avoid reflection (and is probably even better in performance).

```
SuperClass createObject(Namespace namespace, 
                        ArgumentClass1 arg1, 
                        ArgumentClass2 arg2) throws Exception {
    Map<String, SubClassFactory> classMap = ImmutableMap.<String, SubClassFactory>builder()
            .put("subclass1", new SubClassFactory1())
            .put("subclass2", new SubClassFactory2())
            .build();
    return classMap.get(namespace.getString("subclass")).newInstance(arg1, arg2);
}
```

PS: Alternatively those SubClassFactorys could be enums, if you only need one instance per java runtime.

Comment: Is there a reason other than performance to avoid reflection? This requires much more code -- an entire Factory class for each subclass.

Comment: <Disclaimer> Reflection tends to make the code less readable and hinders the IDE to understand your code. You should try to avoid reflection whenever possible. </Disclaimer> (But in your specific case all those arguments don't really match. If you have a better feeling with using reflection - then why not?!)